# Call Symfony controller action from form submit action

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, action

hello i am new to  Symfony 3.4 , i have a form in my html.twig file i want when it's submitted to get the values of it's inputs and pass them to an action in my controller class in order to insert them to the database ,

this is the form (reserver.html.twig) :

```
<h1>reserver</h1>
<form action="" method ="post">
   <input type="text" name="seat">
   <input type="text" name="type">
   <input type="text" name="quantity">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

my conroller class :

```
class reservationController extends Controller
{
    public function CreateReservationtAction(String seat ,String type ,String Quantity){      
        //code to insert into database
        return $this->render("pages/reserver.html.twig");
       }
}
```

this is my routing file :

```
techevent_reservation:
    path:     /res
    defaults: { _controller: techeventBundle:reservation:CreateReservation }
```

i dont have errors yet i want to know the syntax how it will be done and thanks :)

Comment: check this https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/forms.html

Comment: no this is for working with symfony formbuilder , here i have an html form already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action has to point to the path defined in your routing file:

```
<form action="{{ path('techevent_reservation') }}" method ="post">
```

In your controller you can use the `Request` object to get all the parameters of your form, for example:

```
public function CreateReservationtAction(Request $request){
     $seat = $request->request->get('seat');
     $type = $request->request->get('type');
     ...    
}
```

I recommend you to use the [form component](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html) of symfony.